# Geniza for a carton packing?

Tags: kedusha-holiness, genizah-storage

Does a carton box, in which seforim are sold into (a shas for example), needs geniza?

Comment: Why should it? It has no kedusha itself.

Comment: @sabbahillel - I would be interested in knowing if a tallis or tefillin bag has kedushah, and if it does, would it apply to this case as well? (This isn't my question, but curious nonetheless.)

Comment: @ezra One could generalize the question as to what is done with various accessories of sacred items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is,it depends what type of carton box you are referring to. Rabbi Yecheskel Feinhandler in his Ginzei Kodesh pg. 107:13 writes that a box that is used to transport seforim certainly does not need genizah(Rav Eliyashiv and Rav Nissim Karelitz). However, a cardboard box that holds the actual seforim will depend on what its use is for. If it is a flimsy box that is just to hold them together, then they can be thrown out. A cardboard box which is used and not thrown out for a very long time is considered to be a tashmish of kedusha and should be put in genizah.

However, in a case where the box is made to look nice it could be that one would need to put it in genizah. In conclusion, it seems that the main determining factor is if one uses cardboard box for a while after purchasing or not. If right after they buy the seforim and don't want the box then they can throw it out(maybe even a nice box). However,if one leaves them in the box then one makes them into a tashmish kedusha and would require genizah. See footnotes 34 and 35 for the whole discussion.

Comment: This is a good source. +1. It makes sense according to Aruch Hashulchan that holds the shelves of bookcases used solely for sfarim would need need geniza. But Mishna Berurah holds they are tashmishei tashmishei so they do not. I can't imagine how M.B. would think cardboard is any more chamur.

Comment: @user6591 if you check the footnotes it seems Rav Eliyashiv says the same as MB,check it out if you can

Comment: I'll try to get my hands on that seffer. Thanks.